# ImportError: cannot import name 'async contextmanager'

Tags: python, selenium

I am using
**windows 10,
python 3.6**

I am running a selenium project
my code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

**I get this error:**

```
  from contextlib import (contextmanager, asyncio contextmanager) ImportError: cannot import name 'async contextmanager' Process finished with exit code 1
```

[**Error photo**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f4B7.png)

Comment: Did you try python's new version.

Comment: what is the exact version of your python?

Comment: @SushenBiswas No, I am using python 3.6

Comment: @ManishankarVakta Use python New version contextlib will be available for new persion.

Comment: You need at minimum Python 3.7 for [`contextlib.asynccontextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager) as documented.

Comment: @SushenBiswas I try this code with the new version of python 3.9 and its works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python New Version.

**python 3.9 will be working in this case.**

for more details you can read:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager